# Replace character in file based on position

Tags: linux, sed, dd, unicode, character-encoding

I work on the encoding of a file, from `unknown-8bit` to `UTF-8`.
but I got an error message.

```
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 136828
```

So I did a search in the file with the position like this :

```
cat file | dd bs=1 skip=136828 count=1 2>/dev/null
```

And I found the character that poses the problem.

Now I want to replace this character with `?`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Use two `dd`s - one up to that char, the second from char+1 till end.

Comment: How many bytes is the character?

Comment: @RudiC Can you tell me please how can I use two dd ?

Comment: @Kusalananda I thing one character but I m not sure for all cases

Comment: What sort of file? By your post, it is text in some 8-bit encoding. Which one (file(1) should be able to tell you). Or you know it is e.g. Latin1, some Greek or Japanese encoding. The translation to UTF *will* depend on the original encoding! Try other options, they might handle the error more gracefully. I've used recode(1) for several conversions, but no illegal characters as I recall. Generally speaking, emacs(1) is quite adept at swallowing almost anything, perhaps that is the fastest way to zero in and correct the delinquent. On the other hand, an illegal character in an 8-bit encoding is

Comment: like e.g. `dd if=file of=YYYY bs=1 count=99; printf "?" >> YYYY; dd if=file of=YYYY bs=1 skip=100 oflag=append conv=notrunc`.

Comment: @G.Saleh It is clear that it is one _character_, but depending on the encoding it may be several _bytes_ long.

Comment: If you do not know the encoding, then what encoding is `iconv` assuming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the byte at offset 136828 with `?`, you can do:

```
printf '?' | dd bs=1 seek=136828 conv=notrunc of=thefile
```

Comment: It's working for me thanks